# Add button to bottom of screen which does not scroll

Tags: blackberry

I'd like to a add a button to the bottom of the screen which does not disappear from the screen if I scroll horizontally.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your button(s) to a Manager, e.g. FlowFieldManager, then use setStatus.  I use this in my code and it works fine.  What problems are you having with setting focus?

Answer (score 0):

setStatus seems to do the trick. Having some problems though with setting its focus.

Comment: This "answer" would be better as a comment on DaveJohnston's answer